# sed not working from java program, but the input line works from terminal

Tags: java, linux, sed

When I enter the line:

```
sed -i 's/DNS1="8.8.8.8"/DNS1="8.8.4.4"/' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

I get the desired result (i.e. 8.8.8.8 is replaced with 8.8.4.4), however, I have a jave program that passes the same command as shown here:

```
public static void swapDns() throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process ps;

    String cmd[] = {"sed","-i","'s/DNS1=\"8.8.8.8\"/DNS1=\"8.8.4.4\"/'","/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0"};
    ps = rt.exec(cmd);
}
```

and it doesn't work. It doesn't change anything. Is there an issue with sed/java, or am I missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the Java program perhaps run with a different environment, perhaps one where sed is not in the path?  Otherwise perhaps it runs as a user who does not have write permission to the network scripts?

Comment: Great!, you could make it setUID root, but running it as sudo is probably better practice.  Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: scratch that, i'm an idiot. it didn't work. I was running the sed command instead of the java program (facepalm)

Comment: So running the java program with sudo makes no difference?

Comment: Nope. I can always change the file with java completely but I do this fairly often in my current programs and sed would make thing easier.

Comment: Why dont you redirect STDERR to a file so you can see if there are errors?  You could try running strace -f on your program and search for write calls to the file.